# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, jar, word-count

I am new to the Hadoop Environment, Just tried a WordCount program, but every time getting the error like

> 3732814800_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for
> appattempt_1623732814800_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 Failing
> this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-06-15 10:45:16.241]Exception from
> container-launch. Container id: container_1623732814800_0004_02_000001
> Exit code: 1 Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A
> required privilege is not held by the client.
>
> Shell output:         1 file(s) moved. "Setting up env variables"
> "Setting up job resources"
>
> [2021-06-15 10:45:16.244]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
> [2021-06-15 10:45:16.245]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
> For more detailed output, check the application tracking page:
> http://DESKTOP-22LEODT:8088/cluster/app/application_1623732814800_0004
> Then click on links to logs of each attempt. . Failing the
> application. 2021-06-15 10:45:17,267 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!

So what I did till now
I just created a Scala class for Hadoop word count program and create a jar file from that

```
package piyush.jiwane.hadoop

import java.io.IOException
import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred._
import org.apache.hadoop.util._

object WordCount {
  class Map extends MapReduceBase with Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable] {
    private final val one = new IntWritable(1)
    private val word = new Text()

    @throws[IOException]
    def map(key: LongWritable, value: Text, output: OutputCollector[Text, IntWritable], reporter: Reporter) {
      val line: String = value.toString
      line.split(" ").foreach { token =>
        word.set(token)
        output.collect(word, one)
      }
    }
  }

  class Reduce extends MapReduceBase with Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable] {
    @throws[IOException]
    def reduce(key: Text, values: Iterator[IntWritable], output: OutputCollector[Text, IntWritable], reporter: Reporter) {
      val sum = values.toList.reduce((valueOne, valueTwo) => new IntWritable(valueOne.get() + valueTwo.get()))
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum.get()))
    }
  }

  @throws[Exception]
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf: JobConf = new JobConf(this.getClass)
    conf.setJobName("WordCountScala")
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[Text])
    conf.setOutputValueClass(classOf[IntWritable])
    conf.setMapperClass(classOf[Map])
    conf.setCombinerClass(classOf[Reduce])
    conf.setReducerClass(classOf[Reduce])
    conf.setInputFormat(classOf[TextInputFormat])
    conf.setOutputFormat(classOf[TextOutputFormat[Text, IntWritable]])
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args(1)))
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args(2)))
    JobClient.runJob(conf)
  }
}
```

the input file for hadoop program

> 11 23 45 17 23 45 88 15 24 26 85 96 44 52 10 15 55 84 58 62 78 98 84

For the reference i have follow the below links

https://blog.knoldus.com/hadoop-word-count-program-in-scala/ =====&&=== https://www.logicplay.club/how-to-run-hadoop-wordcount-mapreduce-example-on-windows-10/ =====&&====== [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913212/org-apache-hadoop-mapred-filealreadyexistsexception)

please help to undestand this
thanks in advance

**EDIT**
after running the program in cmd administrative mode, i got the output like this

```
2021-06-15 11:42:46,421 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 2021-06-15 11:43:01,282 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1623737359186_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:20)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:13)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-06-15 11:43:02,430 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 50% reduce 0% 2021-06-15 11:43:13,872 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1623737359186_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:20)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:13)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168) 2021-06-15 11:43:27,532 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 17% 2021-06-15 11:43:27,562 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1623737359186_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:20)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.scala:13)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-06-15 11:43:28,600 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0% 2021-06-15 11:43:29,628 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100% 2021-06-15 11:43:30,669 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1623737359186_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1623737359186_0001_m_000000 Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

2021-06-15 11:43:30,877 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 43
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=236028
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=130
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=3
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Killed reduce tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=5
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=2 Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=64773
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=24081
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=64773
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=24081
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=64773
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=24081
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=66327552
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=24658944
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=0
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=6
                Input split bytes=96
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=19
                CPU time spent (ms)=873
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=250834944
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=390701056 Total committed heap usage (bytes)=240123904
                Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=250834944
                Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=390774784
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=34 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:876)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:48)
        at piyush.jiwane.hadoop.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

Comment: `CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.` looks like a privilege problem, i.e. the user running your client might not be allowed to create a symbolic link in the location it wants to. Did you follow the "Open cmd in _administrative mode_" right at the start?

Comment: how do we solve this issue @Thomas ??

Comment: no...I just simply open the cmd

ok i will try that one also

Comment: hi @Thomas, i just run the cmd in administrative mode, it show map=100% and reduce=100% but still i got the *Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!* error

Comment: Well, you've got a _different_ error though and should read the messages and causes carefully. Now it seems ti be "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef" which would indicate a problem with your classpath or module path. I'm neither a scala nor Hadoop expert so I can't tell you what the problem actually is but you should look for any library version mismatches or conflicts or libraries missing at runtime.

Comment: ok...thanks @Thomas for your valuable time

Answer (score 2):

The most recent error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef" comes from using an incompatible version of scala. You are using 2.13.x or newer, be sure to downgrade to 2.12.x or older.

Comment: hi @Sheinbergon thanks for your response. I am also getting the error. I am already using Scala version 2.10 you can look into my sbt file


name := "HadoopMapReduce"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"

Comment: Sorry, your last message is not clear enough. Which error are you also getting? Where is your sbt file?

Comment: hi
the same error you got, i was also facing the same error
and yes this is my .sbt file

Comment: How do you run the program in the cluster? It may give an indication as to what's going on

Comment: One thing that's clear is it can't find the class in the classpath. CNFE is very common in JVM languages. That could be for various reasons. 
Can you share your sbt please? How are you running it? How are you packaging your jar? 

As an aside, I am surprised that someone is still doing Hadoop map-reduce in 2021. If you are doing it for your learning, this is not the most useful skill for 2021 tbh.